# Javascript function await is only valid in async functions

Tags: javascript, php, html

have this app that uses OCR to read image text and convert it to JSON array then write it to an HTML table and export it as an Excel Worksheet by using phpspreedsheet the app was working so far so good until I played around it and missed up something after that Javascript function is not working anymore so it should work to write the table content to an Excel file by `[Change.php]`

prepare.js

```
function readFile(fileName) {
  console.log({ fileName });

  return await Tesseract.recognize(fileName, 'ara', {
  
    logger: m => console.log(m)
  });

}
function parseDataFromTextAndPropertyNames(text, propertyNames) {
  console.log({ text, propertyNames });

  return propertyNames
    .reduce((table, key) =>
      Object.assign(table, {

        [ key ]: RegExp(`${ key }\\W+(\\w+)`)
          .exec(text)?.[1] ?? ''

      }), {});
}
function writeParsedTextDataAsJSON(fileName, table) {
  console.log({ table });
   JSON.stringify({ table });

  // fake it ...
  return (await new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(() => {

      console.log({ fileName, json: JSON.stringify({ table }) });
      resolve({ success: true });

    }, 1500)
  ));
}

console.log('... running ...');

function start(filenames) {
  const { data: { text } } = await readFile(filenames);

  const data = await
    parseDataFromTextAndPropertyNames(text, ['نقطة الخدمة', 'رقم العداد']);
 document.getElementById("dvjson").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4);
 const final = [JSON.stringify(data)];
 const ff = [JSON.parse(final)];
 constructTable('#table',ff);
 htmlstring = getElementById('table').innerHTML();
$.post('change.php', {string:htmlstring}).done(function(response){
      alert("done");
});
  console.log({ result });
}


// construct JSON array to HTML Table

 function constructTable(selector,data) {
             
            // Getting the all column names
            var cols = Headers(data, selector); 
  
            // Traversing the JSON data
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var row = $('<tr/>');  
                for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < cols.length; colIndex++)
                {
                    var val = data[i][cols[colIndex]];
                     
                    // If there is any key, which is matching
                    // with the column name
                    if (val == null) val = ""; 
                        row.append($('<td/>').html(val));
                }
                 
                // Adding each row to the table
                $(selector).append(row);
            }
        }
         
        function Headers(data, selector) {
            var columns = [];
            var header = $('<tr/>');
             
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var row = data[i];
                 
                for (var k in row) {
                    if ($.inArray(k, columns) == -1) {
                        columns.push(k);
                         
                        // Creating the header
                        header.append($('<th/>').html(k));
                    }
                }
            }
             
            // Appending the header to the table
            $(selector).append(header);
                return columns;
        }

setTimeout(function() { 
      
        document.getElementById("loadspinne").style.display ="none";

        document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
      
    }, 8000);
```

prepare.php

```
<script src='scripts\prepare.js'></script>
<?php
if (!empty($target_file)){
    echo '<script>start("'.$target_file.'")</script>';
}
?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.16.2/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/tesseract.js@v2.1.0/dist/tesseract.min.js'></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style\main.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/bd514e8cb4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src='excelexportjs.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <center>
        <div id="loadspinne" style="width: 12rem; height: 12rem; color:#0A9ACD;" class="spinner-border" role="status"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="animate__animated animate__backInDown mx-auto d-block" style="display:none !important;" id="message">
        <h4 style="font-family:Hana; font-size:32px; font-weight:bold;">تم تكوين كشف بنجاح</h4>
        </div>
    </center>
    <div class="container mt-5 ">
    <div style="display:none;" id="dvjson"></div>
    <table align="center" id="table"  border="1" style="display:none;"></table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Change.php

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\IReader;
$htmlString = $_GET['htmlstring'];

$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Html();
$spreadsheet = $reader->loadFromString($htmlString);

$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xls');
$writer->save('ddd.xls'); 

$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load("ddd.xls");

$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(false);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(false);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(16);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(13);

$sheet->getStyle('A1:B1')->getFont()
    ->setName('Arial')
    ->setSize(14)
    ->setBold(true);
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('ddd.xlsx');
// header('Location: ddd.xlsx');
?>
```

Cosnole Log [Errors]:-

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules (at prepare.js:4:10)
upload.php:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: start is not defined
    at upload.php:4:9
(anonymous) @ upload.php:4
```

Comment: Change `function readFile` to `async function readFile`. Also `writeParsedTextDataAsJSON` and `start`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is  you are missing the `async` keyword in some functions, because whenever you use `await` it is mandatory to be used the [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) keyword

> An async function is a function declared with the async keyword, and
> the await keyword is permitted within it. The async and await keywords
> enable asynchronous, promise-based behavior to be written in a cleaner
> style, avoiding the need to explicitly configure promise chains.

```
async function readFile(fileName) {
  console.log({ fileName });

  return await Tesseract.recognize(fileName, 'ara', {
  
    logger: m => console.log(m)
  });

}
```

---

```
async function parseDataFromTextAndPropertyNames(text, propertyNames) {
  console.log({ text, propertyNames });

  return propertyNames
    .reduce((table, key) =>
      Object.assign(table, {

        [ key ]: RegExp(`${ key }\\W+(\\w+)`)
          .exec(text)?.[1] ?? ''

      }), {});
}
```

---

```
async function start(filenames) {
  const { data: { text } } = await readFile(filenames);

  const data = await
    parseDataFromTextAndPropertyNames(text, ['نقطة الخدمة', 'رقم العداد']);
 document.getElementById("dvjson").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4);
 const final = [JSON.stringify(data)];
 const ff = [JSON.parse(final)];
 constructTable('#table',ff);
 htmlstring = getElementById('table').innerHTML();
$.post('change.php', {string:htmlstring}).done(function(response){
      alert("done");
});
  console.log({ result });
}
```